# Updating widget on day change

Tags: android

What's the best way to call onUpdate on a widget once a day, after the date changes? It's not high priority so it can wait until the phone wakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set an alarm with an `Intent` that your `AppWidgetProvider` receives using the `AlarmManager`.

If you want the alarm to be fired only if the device is awake you should use `ELAPSED_REALTIME` or `RTC` as the alarm type. Make sure your xml file has `updatePeriodMillis` set to 0.

Comment: can the same be achieved without alarm scheduling an alarm ? i mean by listening to any related intents ?